# How to select same word in desc order

Tags: sql

How to select same word in a column in desc order

**Name**

```
Apple
Banana
Orange 
Apple 
Cherry
Cherry
```

**Desire output**

```
Cherry
Cherry
Apple 
Apple
```

Comment: what exactly you want ?. you want apple comes 2 times

Comment: All repeated names are shown in desc order

Comment: you want only repeated names or all names including repeated names

Comment: `order by name desc`?

Comment: Post your desired output here.

Comment: yes. Just like 
Cherry
Cherry
Apple
Apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only repetitive names you can use `COUNT` / `GROUP BY` / `HAVING` for this.

```
SELECT Name
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Comment: how to show all repetitive names? If there are three Apples, how to show them all?

Comment: You can add outer query which selects all rows with repetitive names: `SELECT Name FROM YOUR_TABLE as l
JOIN (
SELECT Name
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1 ) as dbl
ON l.Name = dbl.Name
ORDER BY l.Name DESC`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired output:

```
SELECT name FROM table 
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM table
               GROUP BY name
               HAVING COUNT(name) > 1)
ORDER BY name DESC
```